Построение полетного маршрута дрона по 4 координатам (Python)
Необходимо по области, заданной четырьмя координатами, формировать полетное задание (траекторию) сканирования местности для дрона. Полетное задание должно представлять собой массив точек, через которые будет пролетать дрон. Есть ли готовые библиотеки под питон, которые могут это сделать?
Как примерно должна выглядеть траектория:


Задачка то на три цикла
